# Get item that is present in all arrays (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have an object containing a bunch of arrays like this:

```json
{
    names: [0, 1, 2],
    gender: [2, 5, 1],
    boolean: [7, 2, 1, 6]
}
```

How can I get the value which is present in all arrays, in this case, `1`?

Comment: You will probably need to loop through each property.

Comment: it appears 2 is also present in all the arrays. Does it mean it will always pick the first value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd add another solution that does not make any temporary copies of the original data  which can be useful if the data is larger or memory management is important.

```js
const data = {
    names: [0, 1, 2],
    gender: [2, 5, 1],
    boolean: [7, 2, 1, 6]
};

function findCommon(...arrays) {
    // sort arrays by length so we optimize and iterate first by the shortest array
    arrays.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.length - b.length;
    });
    let results = new Set();
    // for each item in the first array
    for (let item of arrays[0]) {
        // look in other arrays for this value
        let found = true;
        for (let i = 1; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            if (!arrays[i].includes(item)) {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            results.add(item);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

let results = findCommon(data.names, data.gender, data.boolean);
console.log(Array.from(results));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I think this is the best solution, just because of the fact that I will be using this on large amounts of data. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A way of achieving this is by getting the distinct values for all the key values and then looping through the values, checking the value exists for each key's array.

```js
const obj = {
    names: [0, 1, 2],
    gender: [2, 5, 1],
    boolean: [7, 2, 1, 6]
}

// [1] Get the object's keys
const keys = Object.keys(obj);

// [2] Get distinct values by combining all the key arrays.
const distinctValues = [...new Set(keys.reduce((all, curr) => {
   return all.concat(obj[curr]);
}, []))];

// [3] Filter the distinct values by checking each value against
//     the key's array
const presentInAll = distinctValues.filter((value) => {
   return keys.every((key) => obj[key].includes(value));
});

console.log(presentInAll);
```